# C++ Threading which takes a SOCKET parameter

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets

I am currently working on my senior project, and the project is almost complete, however I need to implement multi-threading in VisualStudio 2010 which does not support C++11. Therefore I am using this as a source for multi-threading (suggested by my instructor) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682516(v=vs.85).aspx and I am completely lost on how to implement this with a SOCKET.

My issue is how can I use my already coded socket with multi-threading. The following is what I have thus far.

```
typedef struct SenderData {

SOCKET socConnection;

} SENDERDATA, *PSENDERDATA;


DWORD WINAPI SenderThreadFunction( LPVOID lpParam){ 
HANDLE hStdout;
PSENDERDATA pDataArray;

TCHAR msgBuf[BUF_SIZE];
size_t cchStringSize;
DWORD dwChars;

// Make sure there is a console to receive output results. 

hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
if( hStdout == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
    return 1;

// Cast the parameter to the correct data type.
// The pointer is known to be valid because 
// it was checked for NULL before the thread was created.

pDataArray = (PSENDERDATA)lpParam;

return 0; 
}
```

This function has all the commands to start a session in telnet and send a message from a file

```
DWORD WINAPI Sender(LPVOID lpParam){ 
}
```

The following creates the connection, which I initially had in main() but am unsure where to place it now

```
WSADATA wsaData; // Creates wsaData object
WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData); //Initializes Winsock
//Creates the socket object named "soc(Connection"
SOCKET socConnection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

SOCKADDR_IN Addr;
HOSTENT* Host = gethostbyname("smtp.com");
Addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(inet_ntoa(*(in_addr*)Host->h_addr_list[0]));
Addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
Addr.sin_port = htons(25);
```

This would be called in main() if I were not using threading

```
if (connect(Connection, (SOCKADDR*)&Addr, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    cout << "Connection Failed" << endl;
```

How would I place the previous code to launch when the following code is executed in main()?
I am very new at C++ and I greatly appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

```
hThreadArray[0] = CreateThread( 
        NULL,                   // default security attributes
        0,                      // use default stack size  
        Sender,       // thread function name
        pDataArray[0],          // argument to thread function 
        0,                      // use default creation flags 
        &dwThreadIdArray[0]);   // returns the thread identifier
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you are having?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I do not know how to call the connect function in the Sender thread, while also having the Connection already created. Basically is there a way to call the Sender function, and it will create the connection and send the data?

Comment: In my opinion C++11 wouldn't make your task easier at all and VS2010 also has some C++11 features. Your problem is rather multithreading related and learning multithreading is not a few hour or few day course especially in C/C++. The example you linked is also a C example not a C++ one. The correct C++ implementation would wrap the threading into a thread class that makes things a lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that you want to run in a thread needs to be inside the `Sender()` function that you are passing to `CreateThread()`.  So that would be all of your socket calls (other than `WSAStartup()` and `WSACleanup()`, which should only be called once).

Something like this:

```
DWORD WINAPI Sender( LPVOID lpParam)
{ 
    // Make sure there is a console to receive output results. 
    HANDLE hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    if( hStdout == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
        return 1;

    HOSTENT* Host = gethostbyname("smtp.com");
    if (!Host)
    {
        cout << "Unable to resolve smtp.com" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    //Creates the socket object named "soc(Connection"
    SOCKET socConnection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (socConnection == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cout << "Socket Failed" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    SOCKADDR_IN Addr = {0};
    Addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    Addr.sin_addr = * (in_addr*) Host->h_addr_list[0];
    Addr.sin_port = htons(25);

    if (connect(socConnection, (SOCKADDR*)&Addr, sizeof(Addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Connection Failed" << endl;
        closesocket(socConnection);
        return 1;
    }

    ...

    closesocket(socConnection);
    return 0; 
} 

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData; // Creates wsaData object
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData); //Initializes Winsock

    DWORD dwThreadId;
    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread( 
        NULL,                   // default security attributes
        0,                      // use default stack size  
        &Sender,                // thread function name
        NULL,                   // argument to thread function 
        0,                      // use default creation flags 
        &dwThreadId);

    ...

    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);

    DWORD ExitCode = 0;
    GetExitCodeThread(hThread, &ExitCode);

    CloseHandle(hThread);

    if (ExitCode != 0)
    {
        ...
    }

    ...

    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much man! I really appreciate it! I've been banging my head on this all day. Your the man!